# PHP ORDER BY, DESC, LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I'm hoping for some help:
I am trying to output a mysql data table that users can view and arrange by various select fields. I want the data to automatically arrange in date order (newest first) and limited to 10 results per page.

I have the following script excerpt (I have truncated it for brevity happy to post more if necessary)...

```
<!-- **** THIS CODE CREATES THE FORM ****-->
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="deals.php">

<!-- **** THIS CODE IS FOR THE "FROM" DATE ****-->
<label for="from">From</label>
<input name="from" type="text" id="from" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["from"]; ?>" />
Results will only show offers that have been listed since this date. Leave blank for all offers.

<!-- **** THIS CODE IS FOR THE "TO" DATE ****-->
</p>
<label for="to">To</label>
<input name="to" type="text" id="to" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["to"]; ?>"/>
Results will only show offers that run until this date. Leave blank for all offers.

<label>Country</label>
<select name="country">
<option value="">--Any--</option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY country ORDER BY country";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row["country"]."'".($row["country"]==$_REQUEST["country"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["country"]."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
Only shows offers from the selected country.
```

// *****************************************
// *******     REPEATED FOR EACH VARIABLE (I SHOULD HAVE SET IT UP AS AN ARRAY REALLY      *******************************
// *****************************************

```
if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>'') 
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= ' ORDER BY from_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10 ".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_Seller.$search_country.$search_id.$search_Offer.$search_Item.$search_Description.$search_Brand.$search_Was.$search_Now;
}


else if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'') 
{$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date  >= ' ORDER BY from_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_Seller.$search_country.$search_id.$search_Offer.$search_Item.$search_Description.$search_Brand;
}


else if ($_REQUEST["to"]<>'') 
{$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE to_date <= ' ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 0, 10".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_Seller.$search_country.$search_id.$search_Offer.$search_Item.$search_Description.$search_Brand.$search_Was.$search_Now;}

else {$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." ORDER BY from_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10  ".$search_Seller.$search_country.$search_id.$search_Offer.$search_Item.$search_Description.$search_Brand.$search_Was.$search_Now;
}
```

This works perfectly when outputting the initial table, however, once users input any data I get the error

```
"request "Could not execute SQL query" SELECT * FROM newoffers ORDER BY from_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10 AND country='UK'"
```

So I'm guessing there is a problem with the syntax?
I have tried re-arranging the final part so it reads:

```
else {$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"].  .$search_Seller.$search_country.$search_id.$search_Offer.$search_Item.$search_Description.$search_Brand.$search_Was.$search_Now; "ORDER BY from_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10";
}
```

RESULT: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `'"ORDER BY from_date DESC LIMIT' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/iratebjj/public_html/dealstest.php on line 267`

Please check out http://www.iratebjj.com/dealstest.php to see the script in action. 
If anyone has any suggestions I had really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Hope this post is ok. I think I've followed all the guidelines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your mistake

```
$search_Now; "ORDER BY from_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10";
```

You should concatenate `"ORDER BY from_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10"` after `$search_Now` and add a space

```
$search_Now." ORDER BY from_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10"
```

You also need to add `WHERE 1 = 1` condition after `$SETTINGS["data_table"]` since the following variables seem to begin with `AND`: `$search_Seller`, `$search_country`, `$search_id`, `$search_Offer`, `$search_Item`, `$search_De‌​scription`, `$search_Brand`, `$search_Was`, `$search_Now`.

The last `else` block should be as follows

```
else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE 1 = 1 ";
    $sql .= $search_Seller.$search_country.$search_id.$search_Offer.$search_Item.$search_Description.$search_Brand.$search_Was.$search_Now." ORDER BY from_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have replaced the original block to this : else {$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"].  .$search_Seller.$search_country.$search_id.$search_Offer.$search_Item.$search_Description.$search_Brand.$search_Was.$search_Now." ORDER BY from_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10";
} but still getting the error message: request "Could not execute SQL query" SELECT * FROM newoffers AND country='UK' ORDER BY from_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10    >>>>>>>>> Did I do something wrong? Thanks for your help

Comment: See the updated answer, I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your query formation is wrong. The condition `AND country='UK'` should go in a `WHERE` condition and not after `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM newoffers 
WHERE country='UK'
ORDER BY from_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Comment: Thanks but there are several user input fields (one of which is 'country' this is where the'UK' part comes in). Is there a way I can add all these fields to the code you have suggested?

Comment: @Geoff, yes you can. Just include all the conditions in `WHERE` clause. Example, if you have mutiple user inputs for country then you can use a `IN` operator like `WHERE country in ('UK','US','IN')` (OR) for multiple separate fields use `AND`/`OR` condition to plumb the conditions like `WHERE country='UK' and city = 'london' or zip = '0099887766'`